# Do data need to be normally distributed by group or together?

Tags: normality-assumption

I have two groups, both male soccer players divided into professional and amateur, with knee proprioception scores for each player scored from 0-50. When analysed together they are not normally distributed, but when analysed as two groups individually they are. Which way should I do it? I can't decide if they should be assessed for normality together or separately, which will decided if I run independent samples t-tests or Mann-Whitney U-test.

Comment: To what does "it" refer in "Which way should I do it"? What analysis are you intending to perform? Have you searched our site for similar questions about normality?

Answer (score 2):

The data only need to be normal 'by group'.  More specifically, the *residuals* need to be normally distributed, not your response (proprioception scores) marginally.  To understand this further, it may help to read my answer here: [What if residuals are normally distributed, but y is not?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33320/7290)